# Adding a complex sum term by term

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, summation

If $f$ is a function of a complex number $z=a+b i$, then under what conditions can the sum
$$ \sum_{ \vert b \vert <B} f(z) $$ be written as
$$ \sum_{ 0 \leq b <B } (f(z)+f(\bar{z})), $$
where $\bar{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$ and $B>0$? What about if $B \to \infty$? My confusion with this question is due to there be conditions on when sums in general can be added term by term.

Comment: When the sum converges absolutely, you can safely rearrange the order.

Comment: Does that need to be true when $B$ is finite? @TravorLZH

Comment: What does $\sum_{0 \leq b <B} f(z)$ even mean?

Comment: The sum of the function $f(z)$ taken over the imaginary part of $z$ that are $\geq 0$ but less than $B$. There was an error in the question that has now been fixed. @MartinR

Comment: Do you really want to add $f(a+ib)$ for all real values $a, b$ with $|b| < B$? That are uncountably many terms to add.

Comment: $a$ would be fixed. So whether there are uncountably many terms to add with $\vert b \vert <B$ depends on how many $z$ there are such that $\vert \Im z \vert <B$. @MartinR

Comment: @MartinR I see now that the question was a bit ambiguous in that regard.